# How to trigger Azure Durable Functions from Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-durable-functions

I have done Durable Function Python tutorial and deployed to Azure Functions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode

I have succesfully tested triggering Function by (not changed tutorial code yet) http://.azurewebsites.net/api/orchestrators/HelloOrchestrator

I'm reading durable function tip from
http://datanrg.blogspot.com/2020/10/using-durable-functions-in-azure-data.html

How to trigger with Azure Data Factory?

```
1. I tried to add "Azure Function" activity from Azure Data Factory
2. I created Linked Service and entered function name "orchestrators/{HelloOrchestrator}"
3. Selected Method as POST
4. Body set as {"timezone":"Eastern Standard Time"}
4. Add Trigger => " Operation on target Azure Function1 failed: Call to provided Azure function 'orchestrators/{HelloOrchestrator}' failed with status-'InternalServerError' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - InternalServerError.'. "
```

I wonder if use wrong activity?

Comment: Did you try checking in exception logs from Application insights or debug logs from KUDU ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right activity, you can maybe just change to a unique name apart from the ones in the document you are refering. Make sure to rename in all references.

Recheck if you have the right function name though:

> Replace the complete place holder `orchestrators/{FunctionName}` with
> function name `orchestrators/HelloOrchestrator`

Where **HelloOrchestrator** represents the **DurableFunctions-Orchestrator** triggered by an HTTP starter function. Not the HTTP starter function itself.

The function name you supposed to provide in the function activity is DurableFunctions-Orchestrator's. Make sure you have updated **route** parameter in DurableFunctions-Starter bindings to `orchestrators/HelloOrchestrator`

Further, to check the details of the internal error you would have to check the functions log. Application insights log can be checked for exceptions thrown from triggering the function app.

To access [Kudu service](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki), follow below steps:

> Go to your function app in portal -> Under `Development Tools` select
> Advanced tool -> Debug Console (CMD) -> LogFiles -> Application (
> C:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions) -> Select folders accordingly
> -> log file.